# Policycenter does not send account updates to billincenter

Tags: guidewire

I'm developing a Policycenter integration with BillingCenter. I did the initial step-by-step according to the documentation, but when changing some field of an account in PolicyCenter, the synchronization is not performed as in BillingCenter.

I need to sync PolicyCenter account updates with BillingCenter but I couldn't find anything specific in the documentation

Comment: may be account details flows to Contact manager to BC if any edits on PC.. am not sure

Answer (score 5):

1. PC will only send account updates if there are bound policies on the account.  So if you have no bound periods, this is normal behavior.  Assuming you do have bound periods, check the following:
2. By default, PolicyCenter will have the StandAloneBillingSystemPlugin.gs and StandAloneBillingSummaryPlugin.gs implementations enabled. This will result in PC not attempting to communicate with BC at all. Ensure that the plugin configurations IBillingSystemPlugin.gwp and IBillingSummaryPlugin.gwp are configured to use BCBillingSystemPlugin.gs and BCBillingSummaryPlugin instead.
3. Check the contents of suite-config.xml to ensure that the configuration of your BC instance URL looks correct.  Also, make sure BC is running and accessible.
4. Check that the “Billing System” event fired rule is enabled in modules/configuration/config/Rule Sets/EventMessage/Event Fired.  You should see a tick mark on “Billing System” when you open this in studio..
5. Check to make sure that the message destination itself isn’t explicitly disabled. In PolicyCenter, go to Message Queues, and make sure that the status of the Billing System message destination is not “suspended”. Make sure that the amount of unsent messages is 0. If you do see there is a non-zero number of messages there, check your logs to get more context.  Report back here with what you find in the logs and I can provide some more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try preUpdate (DemoPreUpdate.gs)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you enable BillingSystemPlugin in PolicyCenter?
2. If its already enabled, Check if your suite-config has an entry for your local BillingCenter.
3. If the above both are in place, check the BillingTransport sendMessage method.